# How to redirect to application root using the IIS7 URL Rewrite Module?

Tags: iis, web-applications, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have tried:

1) I tried empty string first:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Result:

```
HTTP 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The substitution URL for the current action cannot be empty.
```

2) Maybe I should omit the `url` attribute:

```
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Same result:

```
HTTP 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
The substitution URL for the current action cannot be empty.
```

3) What about the ASP.NET way:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="~" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Tries to redirect to `{APP_ROOT}/~`.

4) Last try:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

As expected, it redirects to the root of the server...

I'd like to find some clean generic solution. (I cannot use some concrete `/myCurrentAppPath`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works better:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="." redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

For now try this, it's not clean but it works:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="?" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me know if you find better solution:)